# mongodb pull element from multidimensional array

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi i have the following array and i want to pull the array with productId 100343

```
Array(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 5388a02c8ead0ebf048b4569
        )

    [cartId] => 14ce496ac194d5d8ee8d0cd11bd3ef5a
    [products] => Array
        (
            [100343] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 100343
                    [quantity] => 13
                    [name] => a
                )

            [100344] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 100344
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [name] => ab
                )

            [100345] => Array
                (
                [productId] => 100345
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [name] => abc
                )

        )

)
```

I've tried like this but it doesn't work

```
$c->update(
    $aQuery, 
    array(
        '$pull' => array('products'=>array('productId'=>'100343'))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an array. Arrays in MongoDB are different in concept to what PHP calls an array, so the structure you have there is the same as this JSON representation:

```js
{
    "products": {
        "100343": {
            "productId": 100343,
            "quantity": 13,
            "name": "a"
        },
        "100344": {
            "productId": 100344,
            "quantity": 3,
            "name": "ab"
        },
        "100345": {
            "productId": 100345,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "abc"
        }
    }
}
```

That sort of structure is just a use of sub-documents and is not an array in the sense as used by MongoDB. To remove the entry as you want with this structure you use the [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator.

```php
$c->update(
    $aQuery, 
    array(
        '$unset' => array('products.productId.100343' => "")
    )
);
```

But really you need to change your data, so to serialize a proper array for MongoDB you need to structure code like this:

```php
$data = array(
    "products" => array(
         array(
             "productId" => 100343,
             "quantity" => 13,
             "name" => "a"
         ),
         array(
             "productId" => 100344,
             "quantity" => 3,
             "name" => "ab"
         ),
         array(
             "productId" => 100345,
             "quantity" => 1,
             "name" => "abc"
         )
     )
 );
```

That produces a JSON structure that looks like this:

```js
{
    "products":[
        {
            "productId":100343,
            "quantity":13,
            "name":"a"
        },
        {
            "productId":100344,
            "quantity":3,
            "name":"ab"
        },
        {
            "productId":100345,
            "quantity":1,
            "name":"abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

That is what MongoDB calls an array, so now you can use the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator correctly:

```js
$c->update(
    $aQuery, 
    array(
        '$pull' => array( 'products.productId' => 100343 )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it! this how i managed to fix it $oCartsCollection->update($aQuery,array('$pull' => array('products' => array('productId' => 100344)))); but now i have problems incrementing the quantity

Comment: @user3683999 Incrementing should be straightforward, you just need to match the element you want to update in your query. See the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator documentation for more information, or feel free to ask another question.

Comment: $oCartsCollection->update($aQuery,array('$inc'=>array(products.0.quantity'=>1))); but this becomes a real problem because i have no reference of the position.

Comment: @user3683999 Look at the link I gave you in the last comment. If that is not clear enough and you need additional help then post anther question rather an ask additional questions in comments.

Comment: posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967374/mongodb-inc-a-field-inside-an-array