# mongodb $inc a field inside an array

Tags: php, mongodb

hi i have the follwing array structure

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 538978ce8ead0ec1048b456c
        )

    [cartId] => 98374319ff71dbc3a84b842b7a443cf7
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 100343
                    [quantity] => 17
                    [name] => a
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 100344
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [name] => ab
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [productId] => 100345
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [name] => abc
                )

        )
```

And i'm having problems to increment the quantity of the products based on the productId

I now use the position **but i have no reference on id**

```
 $oCartsCollection->update(array('cartId'=>'98374319ff71dbc3a84b842b7a443cf7'), array('$inc' => array('products.0.quantity'=>1)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add to your query to select and element from your array and then use the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in order to match that position:

```
$oCartsCollection->update(
    array(
        'cartId'=>'98374319ff71dbc3a84b842b7a443cf7',
        'products.productId' => 100343
     ), 
    array('$inc' => array('products.$.quantity'=>1)));
```

The "dot" notation method is fine for accessing the `productId` element in this case. For multiple fields to match use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) instead

```
$oCartsCollection->update(
    array(
        'cartId'=>'98374319ff71dbc3a84b842b7a443cf7',
        'products' => array(
            '$elemMatch' => array(
                'productId' => 100343,
                'name' => 'a'
            )
        )
     ), 
    array('$inc' => array('products.$.quantity'=>1)));
```

Comment: Thanks now i understand the usage of $.